# Pull request Auto merge is not allowed for this repository

Tags: github

```
Run gh pr merge --merge --auto "33"
  gh pr merge --merge --auto "33"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    PULL_REQUEST_NUMBER: 33
    GH_TOKEN: ***
GraphQL: ["Pull request Auto merge is not allowed for this repository"] (enablePullRequestAutoMerge)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Where does one enable this in the repository?

Answer (score 5):

Go to the Settings of your repository, make sure you're in General and scroll towards the bottom of General till you find this:

[image]